# Netsuite get CSV file contents

Tags: javascript, csv, netsuite

I'm trying to create a suitelet to allow users to upload a CSV file. Once loaded, it should get file contents and do something with it. Problem with the code below is that it's showing some kind of encoded text instead of the CSV content. It outputs fine when I upload a Txt file. I've tried to set the encoding as well but doesn't work.

```
         var file = request.getFile("custpage_file");
         //file.setEncoding("UTF-8");
         var html = file.getValue();
         response.write(html);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works. It was from an older post I made to the NS User group. I think NS has a decoder that works although it's not documented. i.e. you can also try `nlapiDecode(file.getValue(), 'base64');`

```
function getFileValue(file){
    if(file.getType() == "EXCEL") return normalize(Base64.decode(file.getValue()));
    return normalize(file.getValue());
}

function normalize(val){ return val.replace("\r\n","\n");}

/**
*
*  Base64 encode / decode
*  http://www.webtoolkit.info/
*
**/

var Base64 = {

    // private property
    _keyStr : "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=",

    // public method for encoding
    encode : function (input) {
        var output = "";
        var chr1, chr2, chr3, enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
        var i = 0;

        input = Base64._utf8_encode(input);

        while (i < input.length) {

            chr1 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
            chr2 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
            chr3 = input.charCodeAt(i++);

            enc1 = chr1 >> 2;
            enc2 = ((chr1 & 3) << 4) | (chr2 >> 4);
            enc3 = ((chr2 & 15) << 2) | (chr3 >> 6);
            enc4 = chr3 & 63;

            if (isNaN(chr2)) {
                enc3 = enc4 = 64;
            } else if (isNaN(chr3)) {
                enc4 = 64;
            }

            output = output +
            this._keyStr.charAt(enc1) + this._keyStr.charAt(enc2) +
            this._keyStr.charAt(enc3) + this._keyStr.charAt(enc4);

        }

        return output;
    },

    // public method for decoding
    decode : function (input) {
        var output = "";
        var chr1, chr2, chr3;
        var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
        var i = 0;

        input = input.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g, "");

        while (i < input.length) {

            enc1 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
            enc2 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
            enc3 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
            enc4 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));

            chr1 = (enc1 << 2) | (enc2 >> 4);
            chr2 = ((enc2 & 15) << 4) | (enc3 >> 2);
            chr3 = ((enc3 & 3) << 6) | enc4;

            output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr1);

            if (enc3 != 64) {
                output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr2);
            }
            if (enc4 != 64) {
                output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr3);
            }

        }

        output = Base64._utf8_decode(output);

        return output;

    },

    // private method for UTF-8 encoding
    _utf8_encode : function (string) {
        string = string.replace(/\r\n/g,"\n");
        var utftext = "";

        for (var n = 0; n < string.length; n++) {

            var c = string.charCodeAt(n);

            if (c < 128) {
                utftext += String.fromCharCode(c);
            }
            else if((c > 127) && (c < 2048)) {
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 6) | 192);
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
            }
            else {
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 12) | 224);
                utftext += String.fromCharCode(((c >> 6) & 63) | 128);
                utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
            }

        }

        return utftext;
    },

    // private method for UTF-8 decoding
    _utf8_decode : function (utftext) {
        var string = "";
        var i = 0;
        var c = 0, c1 = 0, c2 = 0;
        var c3 =0;

        while ( i < utftext.length ) {

            c = utftext.charCodeAt(i);

            if (c < 128) {
                string += String.fromCharCode(c);
                i++;
            }
            else if((c > 191) && (c < 224)) {
                c2 = utftext.charCodeAt(i+1);
                string += String.fromCharCode(((c & 31) << 6) | (c2 & 63));
                i += 2;
            }
            else {
                c2 = utftext.charCodeAt(i+1);
                c3 = utftext.charCodeAt(i+2);
                string += String.fromCharCode(((c & 15) << 12) | ((c2 & 63) << 6) | (c3 & 63));
                i += 3;
            }

        }

        return string;
    }
};
```

Comment: The only thing somewhat related that NetSuite provides is `nlapiEncrypt`, but there's no corresponding `nlapiDecrypt`

Comment: sorry yes nlapiDecrypt. It's not documented but  nlapiDecrypt does exist and is useable (at your own risk) in server side code. algorithm needs to be in lowercase.

Comment: In SuiteScript 2.0 there's a convert method in the 'N/encode' module. I understand that this question is quite old and that most likely this was not available when the questions was asked, but perhaps somebody runs into this these days.

Answer (score 1):

SuiteScript 2.0

```
var decode = encode.convert({
    string: stringBase64,
    inputEncoding: encode.Encoding.BASE_64,
    outputEncoding: encode.Encoding.UTF_8
    })
```

Comment: Please add an explanation how it answers the queston. Placing code only is not enough.